How to output a symbol not at the beginning of each line, but at the end?
Here is the code in C. It almost works, except the given symbol is inserted at the beginning of the line, but it should be at the end of each line.
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#define BUF_SIZE 1

int main(int argc, LPTSTR argv[]) {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    HANDLE hIn, hOut;
    DWORD nIn, nOut;
    CHAR Buffer[BUF_SIZE];
    char filename[MAX_PATH];

    if (argc != 3) {
        printf("Usage: lab1 file1 character\n");
        printf("-1");
        return 1;
    }

    hIn = CreateFile(argv[1], GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if (hIn == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        printf("Unable to open input file. Error: %x\n", GetLastError());
        printf("-1");
        return 2;
    }

    char appendChar = *argv[2];

    // Check for valid character
    if (appendChar == '\0' || appendChar == '\n' || appendChar == '\r') {
        printf("Invalid character\n");
        CloseHandle(hIn);
        printf("-1");
        return 3;
    }

    // Form the name of the output file
    strcpy_s(filename, argv[1]);
    //len = atoi(argv[2]);
    int len = argv[2][0];
    char * pos = strstr(filename, ".");

    if (pos == NULL) {
        strcat_s(filename, ".txt"); // Changed to .txt
    }
    else {
        int letter = pos - filename;
        filename[letter + 1] = 't';
        filename[letter + 2] = 'x';
        filename[letter + 3] = 't';
        filename[letter + 4] = '\0'; // Terminate the string
        printf("Output file name: %s\n", filename);
    }

    hOut = CreateFile(filename, GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if (hOut == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        printf("Unable to create output file. Error: %x\n", GetLastError());
        CloseHandle(hIn);
        printf("-1");
        return 4;
    }

    int counter = 0;
    bool endOfLine = true;

    while ((ReadFile(hIn, Buffer, BUF_SIZE, &nIn, NULL) && nIn > 0)) {
        if (Buffer[0] == '\n') {
            endOfLine = true;
            WriteFile(hOut, Buffer, nIn, &nOut, NULL); // Write the newline character
            WriteFile(hOut, &appendChar, sizeof(appendChar), &nOut, NULL); // Append the specified character
            counter++;
        }
        else {
            WriteFile(hOut, Buffer, nIn, &nOut, NULL);
            endOfLine = false;
        }

        if (nIn != nOut) {
            std::cerr << "Write error: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
            CloseHandle(hIn);
            CloseHandle(hOut);
            printf("-1");
            return 5;
        }
    }

    // If the last line does not end with a newline,
    // append the specified character at the end of the file
    if (!endOfLine) {
        WriteFile(hOut, &appendChar, sizeof(appendChar), &nOut, NULL);
        counter++;
    }

    printf("Number of replacements: %d\n", counter);
    CloseHandle(hIn);
    CloseHandle(hOut);

    return 0;
}  

How it works: in the main folder there is a file with some text with the extension .out, at the end of the execution a file with the extension .txt should appear, and the task will be performed: insert the given symbol at the end of each line.
Input data: file with code, file with text, the symbol to be replaced with
You need to do it in C using WinAPI
input file:

output file:


I've already tried everything even peanutbutter?

I mostly see unneeded "C" style coding using the windows API, Have you even tried real C++ code yet? Yyou know the kind of code that uses, std::filesystem, std::iostream/std::fstream and string formating functions like std::format?

"How it works: [too long description]" -- That's how your program works. It might be useful context, but for this question, your code should output one or two lines of pre-determined text. Skip all the functionality not directly needed for "the given symbol is inserted at the beginning of the line, but it should be at the end of each line".

These statements are backwards:
WriteFile(hOut, Buffer, nIn, &nOut, NULL); // Write the newline character
WriteFile(hOut, &appendChar, sizeof(appendChar), &nOut, NULL); // Append the specified character

When you encounter a \n character in the input file, you are writing it to the output file first, then writing the symbol.  That is why it appears at the beginning of the next line.
You need to swap these statements so you write the symbol first, then write the line break.
Also, keep in mind that on Windows, most text files use \r\n for their line breaks, not \n by itself.  You are not checking for \r at all.  You don't want to write out a \r followed by a symbol followed by a \n.  So, you need to detect when \r\n is being used and not write out either character until after the symbol has been written first.

What you are attempting would be much easier if you rewrite the code to use actual C++ features, like std::ifstream/std::ofstream, std::getline(), etc.  For example:
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <filesystem>
#include <clocale>
#include <windows.h>

int main(int argc, LPTSTR argv[]) {
    std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    if (argc != 3) {
        std::cout << "Usage: lab1 file1 character\n";
        std::cout << "-1";
        return 1;
    }

    char appendChar = *argv[2];

    // Check for valid character
    if (appendChar == '\0' || appendChar == '\n' || appendChar == '\r') {
        std::cout << "Invalid character\n";
        std::cout << "-1";
        return 2;
    }

    std::ifstream inFile(argv[1]);
    if (!inFile.is_open()) {
        std::cout << "Unable to open input file.\n";
        std::cout << "-1";
        return 3;
    }

    // Form the name of the output file
    std::filesystem::path filename = argv[1];
    filename.replace_extension("txt");

    std::cout << "Output file name: " << filename << "\n";

    std::ofstream outFile(filename);
    if (!outFile.is_open()) {
        std::cout << "Unable to create output file.\n";
        std::cout << "-1";
        return 4;
    }

    int counter = 0;
    std::string line;

    while (std::getline(inFile, line)) {
        outFile << line << appendChar;
        if (!inFile.eof())
            outFile << '\n';
        if (!outFile) {
            std::cout << "Write error\n";
            std::cout << "-1";
            return 5;
        }
        ++counter;
    }

    std::cout << "Number of replacements: " << counter << "\n";

    return 0;
}  

Online Demo

dasfgfdsadfdd cdfgdsfgd dfsds sfd sad fdsf
*
ddsfdsaf
*
fsdadfcvbcfdsfvbnghftr
*
yjhgfdsfgbn
*
ghfsrewrtghjgfdv
*
ccsdas
*
132432134t*
That's what the code does with the tabs

it says that filename and cout are not defined

@Marchenko I fixed a couple of typos, and added an online demo that shows the code in action.

You wrote the code in C++, but you need it in C

@Marchenko the code you posted in your question has a mix of C and C++ in it. But in any case, the 1st half of my answer addresses the issues with the C code.
